# DrawCalls and Batches Unity

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine

[Batches.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXTrE.jpg)
[Draw calls in profiler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhTOt.jpg)

why is my batches is lower than my draw calls , is this possible to happen?, do you have any idea or suggestion about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.  For example: multi pass shaders can draw the same batch for each pass.